# Does the Torah specify which foods are recommended for weight loss?

Tags: food, health-safety-shmira

We know that kosher foods are good for spiritual health, but does the Torah discuss which foods are good for our physical health (especially for weight loss)?

Comment: Does Torah recommend weight loss altogether?

Comment: @shmosel Only for people for whom it would benefit their health to do so. For others it might recommend weight gain.

Comment: @shmosel apparently yes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhV14Coe68o

Comment: Miguel I recommend this book: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Feldheim-Life-Transforming-Revised-David-Zulberg/dp/1598269771

Comment: @shmosel If many rabbi's consider the Talmud to be part of Torah then maybe. Although I'll admit it's obviously not part of the chumash. This might branch off into a discussion about the semantics of the word "Torah".

Comment: Where does the Talmud recommend weight loss?

Comment: @shmosel Ahhh! Using the lawyer style of questioning eh? Nice one 

Comment: Is that a thumbs-up or a [Talmudic thumb swipe](https://www.queensjewishlink.com/index.php/opinion/72-rabbi-s-musings-amusings/1627-thumbs-up)?

Answer (score 0):

The pshat of this Gemarra is certainly not considered normative halacha, so it's worth looking at the commentaries and speaking to a rabbi and probably a nutritionist, but the Babylonian Talmud says in Tractate Shabbat, p. 140b,

"וְאָמַר רַב חִסְדָּא׃ בַּר בֵּי רַב [דְּלָא נְפִישָׁא לֵיהּ רִיפְתָּא] — לָא לֵיכוֹל יַרְקָא, מִשּׁוּם דְּגָרֵיר. וְאָמַר רַב חִסְדָּא׃ אֲנָא לָא בַּעֲנִיּוּתִי אֲכַלִי יַרְקָא, וְלָא בְּעַתִּירוּתִי אֲכַלִי יַרְקָא. בַּעֲנִיּוּתִי — מִשּׁוּם דְּגָרֵיר. בְּעַתִּירוּתִי — דְּאָמֵינָא׃ הֵיכָא דְּעָיֵיל יַרְקָא, לֵיעוּל בִּשְׂרָא וְכַוְורֵי."

"And Rav Ḥisda further said: A student of a Torah academy who does not have much bread should not eat a vegetable, because it whets the appetite. And Rav Ḥisda said: I neither ate a vegetable in my state of poverty, nor did I eat a vegetable in my state of wealth. In my poverty, I did not eat a vegetable because it whets the appetite. In my wealth, I did not eat a vegetable because I said: Where a vegetable enters, let meat and fish enter instead."

The suggestion is that vegetables 'stimulate the appetite' and should be avoided. I suppose in modern terms Rav Chisda is suggesting a kind of modified Paleo diet.

Comment: This answer on the "Rambam's Weight Loss Program' should be more useful than mine: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127656/contemporary-views-on-the-rambams-diet-guide?rq=1